# iOS 10 Core Data Tutorial - NSPersistentContainer

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-data, xcode8, ios10

I am attempting to follow Apples developer documentation to use CoreData.
I have just started learning Objective-C and now trying to wrap my head around CoreData. I think I have the concept under wraps OO Database.

For the life of me I can't get it to work and all searches I've done bring back either the tutorials for iOS 9 and previous, or for Swift.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

[Core Data - Developer.Apple.Com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata?language=objc)

Comment: Your question is too vague to have a good answer. If you're having specific problems, describe what you tried and what specific problems you had. "I can't get it to work" can only really be answered by pointing you back at the documentation or other introductory tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep things simple only deal with a single managedObjectContext.  If you are using `NSPersistentContainer` this is the `viewContext`.  Make sure to always read and write to core-data only from the main thread.  You will find similar simple setups with a single managedObjectContext in many tutorials.

Once you have mastered that you should learn how to use `NSPersistentContainer` properly.  It is not that hard there are a few simple rules to follow:

- NEVER write to the `viewContext`
- only write using `performBackgroundTask`.
- Do not use any managedObjects or context from `performBackgroundTask`
- Do not use any `viewContext` managedObject inside of performBackgroundTask - pass the objectID and refetch it inside the context.
- don't use newBackgroundContext - it is useful only in very rare situations that you are unlikely to encounter.
- discard all managedObject after a fetch.  If you need to keep a point to a managed object use a fetchedResultsController - even if it is for just one object